# How to pass query string to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page that contains a data from database table.  At the end of every row, there's an Update button that allow users to update that specific row.  I tried to make Id as an readonly input, but whenever I click submit on any row, the value return by $this->input->post() is always the last row Id.  I want it to return the Id at which I click the Submit.

Id Name Action

```
echo form_open('control/edit');

foreach($rs as $db)
{
  $row = array(form_input('id', $db['id']), $db['name'], form_submit('update', 'Update'));
  $this->table->add_row($row);
}

echo $this->table->generate();
```

In the control/edit controller,

```
$this->input->post('id') // always returns the id of the last row.
```

Anyone know how do I do about this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is being passed as call-by-reference rather than actually setting the value, or more simplisticly, that last row's input name of "id" is the last occurance in the html form, which means it will be the only one to get post'd.

Ex:

```
<input name="id" value="a" />
<input name="id" value="b" />
<input name="id" value="c" />
<input name="id" value="d" />
```

If you clicked submit, $this->input->post('id') = 'd';

Try changing your foreach to something like:

```
... form_input("id[{$db['id']}]", $db['id'] ...
```

Your $this->input->post('id') would then be an array, which you can get the key/value with what id was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend attaching a click listener to your update button and adding a field.

Field:

And the javascript onclick for the tablerows would be

```
onclick="document.getElementsByName('selectedRowId')[0].value = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value"
```